# How do I use "git init" to initialize a new folder?

Tags: macos, git, git-init

I want to initialize a folder for a new HTML project.  The folder is called HTML. I want to create ".git"(repository?) in that folder. Here is what I keep getting after I put "git init" after my folder name:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk 
Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git 
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib 

dyld: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk 
Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git 
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

What does this mean? Is there another command I should use? I need to initialize the folder so that .git comes up.

I've tried to fix this on my own by using different folders and nothing is getting created under "git init".  Git is properly installed on my Mac.

Comment: Please show us the exact command you typed.

Comment: Simply typing `git init` while you're in the directory should work. If that's what you're doing and you get those errors, then git is *not* properly installed.

Comment: `git init` is enough to create a repo. If you want to create a bare git repo, thats different.

Comment: I looked into this and was told that my Mac version is older and not compatible with the new Git version. I have Mountain Lion.  Now I want to uninstall Git, and reinstall an older version but don't know.  SMH.

Answer (score 0):

Good introduction here:
http://shaun.boyblack.co.za/blog/2009/03/14/getting-started-with-git-on-mac-os-x/

**git init** (without additional words) creates a new git repo in the current working directory. Navigate to the root folder of your project and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following steps will help you to use "git init"

1. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git
   Based on your OS, use the above link to install git on your machine.
2. After the installation is successful, open terminal. Run git on the terminal and the result will appear as follows[Installed git successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seB7m.png)
3. After this, run git --version to check the git version. Note, there is a space between git and --version.
4. [Checking GIT version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkdzE.png)
5. Now, create a folder where git repo is to be created.
6. After selecting that folder, run, "**git init**"
7. Please check this link for further steps.
   [Git commands not working in Mac terminal: "dyld: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929689/git-commands-not-working-in-mac-terminal-dyld-symbol-not-found-strlcpy-ch)

Answer (score -1):

Please check this thread: [git + mountain lion + dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22920497/git-mountain-lion-dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-not-found-str)

It is for a very similar issue on Mac. What is your Mac OS X version? Did you ever used/configured git on this Mac before?
Can you run commands like `git --version` or `git config -l` ?

Comment: You should flag the question as a duplicate

Comment: Ah gotcha, I didn't check to see what reputation is needed for that.  I've flagged it.  Thanks.

Comment: I am using Mac Lion.  I also posted a question about how to uninstall Git and start over since I cant get past it. I was told on another forum my Mac version is not compat with the new Git.   I want to uninstall it and install an older Git version or uninstall it and update my Mac.  I just need to uninstall it now.

Comment: @April1900 if that case has been closed in your oppinion, you may check the answer that satisfies you best.